# Stay in the same position after a jQuery's slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click a `div` **(x)**, it expands using `.slideDown()`, the height is increased, when I detect a scroll pass by this element **(when x is no longer in viewport)**, using `inview` plugin, I close it with `.slideUp()`, the increased height goes back to its normal state, instead of being at **(y)**, I'm now at **(z)**

After `.slideDown()`

```
x
x
x
x
y  <-- I arrive here with scrolling
y
z
z
```

After `.slideUp()`

```
x
x <-- height decreased
y <-- instead of being here..
y 
z <-- I'm here.
z
```

How can I stay in this same position even after an element's height is decreased?

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JzWNa/)

Comment: can you provide a live demo of your code ?

Comment: @NathanLee ok I'll work on it now.

Comment: I would suggest, use a parent div with fix height, it's very obvious to reduce the height when you slideUp.

Comment: @NathanLee Here is it : http://jsfiddle.net/JzWNa/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `.slideDown()` is triggerd get the current srolltop position of the page and set that scroll position after `.slideUp()` triggered.
You can use the below code.

```
//Get the current position of the page
var pagePosition = $(window).scrollTop();               

//Set page position after `.slideUp()` called
$("html,body").scrollTop(pagePosition);
```

Comment: Logically I'm saving the position of `x`, when I close it, I go back to that position: Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/JzWNa/2/